# Update programmatically "value" and "delta" attributes of Indicators using Plotly gauge charts

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Dear Stackoverflow Members

From the examples illustrated in [**How to make gauge charts in Python with Plotly**](https://plotly.com/python/indicator/),
I wonder whether it is possible to programmatically update the fields, hereinafter:

- `value`
- `delta`

?

**N.B:** By updating programmatically, I mean:

- assigning global variables like `var1`, `var2` to `attributes`, while ensuring - in this case - that their values are passed to `value`, `delta`:

  ```
  fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
  value = var1,
  delta = {'reference': var2},
  gauge = {
      'axis': {'visible': False}},
  domain = {'row': 0, 'column': 0}))
  ```

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the referenced reference example, each value has been modified to correspond to a variable. I created an indicator graph with one row and four columns, with a list of values and a list of reference values to show differences.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

value_list= [200,300,400,500]
delta_list = [160,250,320,400]

fig = go.Figure()

for i,(v,d) in enumerate(zip(value_list, delta_list)):
    #print([0.25*i+0.05, 0.25*i+0.25])
    fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
        value = v,
        delta = {'reference': d}, 
        gauge = {
            'axis': {'visible': False}},
        domain = {'x': [0.25*i+0.05, 0.25*i+0.25], 'y': [0.0, 1.0]}))#{'row': 0, 'column': i+1}))

fig.update_layout(
    grid = {'rows': 1, 'columns': 4, 'pattern': "independent"},
    template = {'data' : {'indicator': [{
        'title': {'text': ""},
        'mode' : "number+delta+gauge",
        'delta' : {'reference': d}}]
                         }}
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great - no need to pass values via an additional ```function.js```, thank you. Best.